# Toggle button does not turn off timer

Tags: java, android, timer

I've got a timer set to excecute a task every 30 seconds for testing purposes and currently it turns on and the timer works but it doesn't toggle off and the task just keeps executing.
Toggle Button Code

```
 @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        Timer myTimer = new Timer();
        MyTimerTask myTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();
        if (isChecked)
        {
          myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(myTimerTask,0,30000);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Check-In will be done every 30 seconds",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
         myTimer.cancel();
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Manual Check-In enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

This code is in the onCreate method

```
 toggler = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglelocationupdate);
        toggler.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

My MainActivity implements `CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are creating a new instance of `Timer` every time the button is clicked. Move the `myTimer` declaration to the class level.

Comment: `Timer myTimer = new Timer();
        MyTimerTask myTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();`
move both those lines or just the  `Timer myTimer = new Timer();` line

Comment: Sorry, copy-paste error on my side. I meant `myTimer` of course.